# django rest pagination on api view decorator

Tags: api, django-rest-framework

im trying to do pagination on my django rest code, but i get the same code when i change the number of the page, this is what im doing to get that page: http://localhost:8000/movies?page=3
When i change the page number i get the same response, idk if i have to send the number of the page or something but i do the same of this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830779/django-rest-framework-apiview-pagination)

I put the entire view code:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def movies(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.query_params.get('id'):
            try:
                id = request.query_params.get('id')
                movie = Movie.objects.get(id=id)
                serializer = MovieSerializer(movie, many=False)
                return Response(serializer.data)
            except Movie.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        movies = Movie.objects.all().order_by('release_date')
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies , many=True, context={'request':request})

        if request.query_params.get('page'):
            paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
            result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(movies, request)
            serializer = MovieSerializer(result_page, many=True, context={'request':request})
            return Response(serializer.data)

        if request.query_params.get('Genre'):
            genreparam = request.query_params.get('Genre')
            genre = Genre.objects.get(name=genreparam)
            queryset = Movie.objects.filter(genre_relation=genre.id).values().order_by('release_date')
            return Response(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
}
```

this is what i get whatever number i send via request params

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Guardians of the galaxy",
    "tagline": "this is a tagline",
    "overview": "this is an overview, starlord in the begins...",
    "release_date": "1971-07-13T03:00:00Z",
    "poster_url": "http\"//posterurl",
    "backdrop_url": "http\"//backdropurl",
    "imdb_id": "idk what is a imdb",
    "genre_relation": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Avengers endgame",
    "tagline": "this is a tagline",
    "overview": "tony stark dies, theres no more happy days, only days",
    "release_date": "2019-07-13T03:00:00Z",
    "poster_url": "http//posterurl",
    "backdrop_url": "http//backdropurl",
    "imdb_id": "idk what is a imdb",
    "genre_relation": [
        1
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You are not using the pagination properly. You need to instantiate the paginator with the request, and then call paginate_queryset. You are merely instantiating a paginator, and then completely ignoring it.
paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(movies, request)
You thus should rewrite this to:
paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(movies, request, view=self)
Note that we here pass view=self, since the LimitOffsetPagination uses self.request, self.response, etc.
Furthermore you should not construct a new serializer, but reuse the existing one, and pass result_page as the queryset:
serializer = MovieSerializer(result_page, many=True, context={'request': request})
Finally you should return the paginated results with:
return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
This will add pagination metadata to the response.
So a full example:
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'PUT'])
def movies(request):
    # ...
    if request.query_params.get('page'):
        paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
        result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(movies, request, view=self)
        serializer = MovieSerializer(result_page, many=True, context={'request':request})
        return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    # ...
Note that using the @api_view decorator is often discouraged. You might want to consider using the @api_view decorator.
```